# Flutter support miltiline on TextFormField

Tags: flutter

i search some issues on flutter `github` and `stackoverflow` to resolve this problem

in below implementation in flutter i can't type `Enter` to have more line in `TextFormField`, i think i set correctly `keyboardType` and `maxLines`, but my keyboard on phone doesn't have `enter` key and that's `next`

```
TextFormField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
    maxLines: 7,
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
),
```

Comment: Have you tried using `textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove  `textInputAction: TextInputAction.next`

```
TextFormField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      maxLines: 7,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      //textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    );
```

or as @Siddharth Patankar commented set `textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline`